# index out of bounds numel = 1

Tags: matlab, function

I'm getting this error:

```
"Attempted to access v(2); index out of bounds because numel(v)=1.
Error in extractperiod10 (line 8)
        v(month)=v(month) + u;"
```

and I can't figure out what's wrong.. I'm calling the function with this:

```
extractperiod10(TEMPUF,@extractperiod, @periodmean,1979,3).
```

The file I'm working with TEMPUF is a matrix with 17166 rows and 7 columns containing temperatures and tof the day with correspnding date.

my extractperiod10.m

```
function v=extractperiod10(file, extractperiod, periodmean,year,column)
v=zeros(12,1);

for month=1:12
    for year=year:year+9
        p=extractperiod(file,year,month,column);
        u=periodmean(p);
        v(month)=v(month) + u;
    end
   v=mean(v);
end
end
```

my periodmean.m(some values are -999 and I don't want them in the calculation):

```
function M=periodmean(values)
invalid = -999;
valid=find(values ~= invalid);
M=mean(values(valid));
end
```

my extractperiod.m

```
function T=extractperiod(file,year,month,col)
y=floor(file(:,1)/100);
match=find(y==year*100 + month);
T=file(match,col);
end
```

EDIT:

```
function v=extractperiod10(file, extractperiod, periodmean,column)
v=zeros(12,1);

for month=1:12
    for y=1970:1979%y=year:1:year:+9 %
        p=extractperiod(file,y,month,column);
        u=periodmean(p);
        v(month)=v(month) + u;
    end
    v(month)=mean(v);
end

v2=zeros(12,1);
for month=1:12
    for y2=2000:2009
        p2=extractperiod(file,y,month,column);
        u2=periodmean(p2);
        v2(month)=v2(month) + u2;
    end
    v2(month)=mean(v2);
end
    v=[v,v2];

end
```

Comment: Calling v = mean(v) reduces v to a single value, so you might want to use an index to store multiple values, like v(month) perhaps?

Comment: It seems that you have matrix dimension mismatch problem when adding v and u. Can you not run in debug mode and find out what your u and v(month) is (size-wise)?

Comment: @hagubear this is what it gave me with the same input as in the 1st post. "Column = 3, file = 17166x7 double, month=1, p=31x1 double, u = -11,8452, v = 12x1 double, year = 1979" Why doesn't it just store the "-11.8452" in v(month(=1))?

Comment: and in v(1) it stored "-64,1516" when it should store 0 + "-11.8452"

Comment: instead of saying `for year=year:year+9` which is quite confusing, can you put `for j = year:1:year+9` for the sake of clarity? Use `j` instead of `year` throughout the rest of your code. Also, are you sure that your `row x column` and `column x row` sizes are not mixed up? You should be doing `v(month,:) = v(month, :) + u;`. Also, try and do this addition on MATLAB workspace without using the function, see what happens.

Comment: @hagubear, Thanks for the help. I changed a bit in the function (posted it at the topic under EDIT:) and it seems to be working now, atleast I hope so. Atleast the output seems logical, hehe. Sorry for bothering, missed the lectures on matlab since I was at the hospital and got an assigment to complete to tomorrow.

Comment: @RasmusNordlander       No problem. Update your question if you think something's gone wrong again :)